# Flask JWT Extended "The specified alg value is not allowed" Error

Tags: flask, jwt, axios, flask-jwt-extended, flask-jwt

When making a request to a flask route that requires a JWT to access using (`@jwt_required` decorator on flask-restful resources), I get a `422 UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY` with the message: `The specified alg value is not allowed`.

When logging in and navigating to the (frontend) route that calls the request:

```
this.axios.get("/jobs").then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
      this.jobs = res.data.jobs;
    });
```

in the same go, it works as expected, however on refresh it then shows the 422 error.
I store the token in localstorage and load it into axios headers like so:

```
const api = {
  init: function() {
    Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);
    Vue.axios.defaults.baseURL = DEV_URL;
  },

  setHeader: function() {
    const token = `Bearer ${getToken()}`;
    Vue.axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = token;
  },
};
```

and call `init()` and `setHeader()` in my `main.js` so I am confused why this is causing an error only after a refresh.

I haven't be able to find any resources on how to remedy the `The specified alg value is not allowed` error. Any assistance would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Can you show us how you generate the token? The algorithm used by the `jwt` is stored in [the header](https://jwt.io/introduction/) - you can set the algorithm `jwt-extended` uses in the [config options](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options.html). On of the tests in the `jwt-extended` [git repo](https://github.com/vimalloc/flask-jwt-extended/blob/master/tests/test_asymmetric_crypto.py) shows how a difference in algorithm can give that error you're getting.

Comment: @elembie thanks for the response. I've been following the basic usage in the docs. The only config options I set were `JWT_SECRET_KEY`, `JWT_BLACKLIST_ENABLED` and `JWT_BLACKLIST_TOKEN_CHECKS`. I didn't change from the default algorithm. The token was generated by: `access_token = create_access_token(identity=data["username"])`.

Comment: I've also just tried changing `JWT_ALGORITHM` to `RS256` and set private and public keys and still have the same issue

Comment: Have you validated that the token is being retrieved properly from the secure store? I'm just thinking the `jwt` might have been modified somehow - maybe print it out on the server and on the client and check it's not changed.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same problem when the JWT token was created in my spring boot auth service but resource service was a flask micro service. I tried the following steps to sort it out,

- I pasted the token in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) Debugger.
- On the right hand side I found the decoded header where the alg value was the following,

```json
    {
      "alg": "HS512"
    }
```

- I put the alg in the app config in the flask resource server as follows,

```python
    app.config['JWT_ALGORITHM'] = 'HS512'
```

After that the error message was gone and I was able to parse information from the decoded token. So you need to find the algorithm by which the token was generated and set the appropriate algorithm in the flask `app.config`.

Answer (score -1):

This can happen if the token was created using a different algorithm then `app.config['JWT_ALGORITHM']`