# Flask JWT Extension throws exception when validating a Google JWT token

Tags: python, jwt, google-openid, flask-jwt-extended, google-openidconnect

I have a SPA application. Each client request contains an `Authorization: Bearer <access_token>` retrieved from google https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect (google creates the JWT token)

When authenticating endpoints (graphQL ones by the way) with `@jwt_required` I got error `The specified alg value is not allowed`

I tried by tweaking [configuration options](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options/) as state [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58514171/flask-jwt-extended-the-specified-alg-value-is-not-allowed-error) without luck. (basically setting `JWT_ALGORITHM` or `JWT_PUBLIC_KEY` to RS256 but then I get either `JWT_PUBLIC_KEY must be set to use asymmetric cryptography algorithm "RS256"` or `Could not deserialize key data.`

Here JWT google shape:

header:

```
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

body:

```
{
  "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
  "azp": "some.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "aud": "some.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "sub": "some_uuid",
  "email": "email@test.com",
  "email_verified": true,
  "at_hash": "",
  "name": "use_full_name",
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/some",
  "given_name": "user_name",
  "family_name": "last_name",
  "locale": "en",
  "iat": 1572189191,
  "exp": 1572192791
}
```

any help appreciated! (keep trying though)

Comment: Did you set `JWT_PUBLIC_KEY` to the public key the JWTs were signed with?

Comment: Hi @KlausD. thanks for your quick answer! How I can find the public Key the google JWT token was signed with? I tried with `kid` key or with `kid` values from `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs` currently I set `app.config['JWT_ALGORITHM'] = 'RS256'` and app.config['JWT_PUBLIC_KEY']  = `{kid}`  error: `Could not deserialize key data.`

Comment: How did you solve the problem? @VicensFayos